# Date is returning the wrong year in US server

Tags: java, datetime

I'm developing code in the U.K, I'm formatting a date field which is working OK in the U.K, when I deploy the code onto the server in the U.S the year of the date is wrong by one year. This is the code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    String dateStr = sdf.format(1293840000000L);
    System.out.println(dateStr);
}
```

In the U.K locally on a windows machine this code correctly outputs:

```
2011-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

On the server in the U.S on a linux box the same code outputs

```
2010-12-31T18:00:00Z
```

It must be some kind of time zone issue?

Comment: What time zones are these? It looks like a few hours difference?

Comment: T00 , T18 T = Timezone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pattern ends with a hardcoded `'Z'` which misleadingly makes you think that it is UTC when it is not. If you use the real time zone:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
```

(no quote around the Z) you will see that the difference is just a timezone offset.

Here is an example that reproduces the problem, which is due to the fact that `SimpleDateFormat` uses the default timezone:

```
Date dt = new Date(1293840000000L);

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
String dateStr = sdf.format(dt);
System.out.println(dateStr); //prints 2010-12-31T18:00:00 -0600

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
dateStr = sdf.format(dt);
System.out.println(dateStr); //prints 2011-01-01T00:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is just one day.. or to be precise few hours

from **31st Dec 2010** to **1st Jan 2011**. Since UK's time is ahead of US

A time in milliseconds like `1293840000000L` represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT. So, the same value for UK and US differs.

Comment: Ergo: the conversion is probably correct (6 hour difference sounds about right for US East coast vs UK time).

Comment: It's just 6 hours, actually.

Answer (score 1):

The [Javadoc page for DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) says

> The date is represented as a Date object or as the milliseconds **since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.**

emphasis mine.  This means that if you want to specify the date as milliseconds (a long), you're responsible for any time zone calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a time zone difference. The United States is several hours behind the UK (the exact difference depends on where you are, specifically).

In this case, it's a six hour difference. I believe that's CST to GMT, so odds are your user has a different locale set. This means the string is correct. If you want the same string, you need to either change the locale or makes sure you're printing the GMT offset.

For example, `DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");`